# Проблема наложения на несколько объектов текстур LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Не понимаю, почему не получается наложить одну и ту же текстуру на объекты, которые я инициализировал на карте

[image: Сами объекты]

Абстрактный класс для инициализации этих объектов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс, чтобы наложить текстуру

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот как это выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот в цикле обрабатываю каждый объект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажи код где происходит отрисовка объектов. Сначала надо отрисовать фон, а потом все остальное.